# How to make irregular size stones procedural textures?

Tags: texturing, procedural, shader-nodes

[image]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to make a procedural stone texture, but i can't figure it out how to make irregular size stones (just like the image), avoiding the brick patterns where every single one of them are the same width and height.

Are there any tutorial on how to make it or a tip on how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it work to take a seamless brick pattern and modify it how you need (such as hue, saturation, brightness, contrast etc). with the shader editor?